# Server set's the current time to it's default time zone

Tags: azure, server, timezone

I have a server that is hosted by azure. The server is located in North Europe so when I try to store a value in my database, it's time is set to the current time of the server's time zone rather than the location where I'm sending the data which results in incorrect time being displayed.
I don't know if there's a way around this. I will really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Always store time as UTC in the database. Always.

Comment: okay. I'm currently doing DateTime.Now (C#) so All I need to do is change it to DateTime.UTCNow right?

Comment: Right. And display it as UTC, or convert to user timezone, but knowing that the DB is UTC. This way you won't have to deal with anomalies like server time vs. client time and DST changes.

Comment: alright cool. Thanks man

Comment: Have a look at this too: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/04/06/changing-the-server-time-zone-on-azure-web-apps/